# TypeScript union error when string is put in an object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component with these props:

```
type Props = {
  items: {
    text: string;
    status?: "processing" | "error" | "info-required";
  }[];
};

const Component: React.FC<Props> = ({ items }) =>
```

When I use the component and set the props inline it works fine:

```
<Component
    items={[
      { text: "a" },
      { text: "b" },
      { text: "c", status: "processing" }
    ]}
  />
```

However when I put the props in an object it errors:

```
const items = [
  { text: "a" },
  { text: "b" },
  { text: "c", status: "processing" }
]

<Component items={items} />
```

> Types of property 'status' are incompatible.
>     Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"error" | "processing" | "info-required"'.
>
> The expected type comes from property 'items' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'

Comment: Typescript is probably guessing that the type of `status` in the `items` variable is `string`. If you copy the type of the `items` property in `Props` over, it'll work. E.g. try `const items: typeof Props['items'] = ...`

Comment: @cbr good thinking :) There is no need for the keyword `typeof` thought, because `Props['items']` already reference `{ text : string, status ?: '...' }`

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT Good catch! I did not even realize that before I read your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, because you haven't defined the type of `const items`, typescript is not sure that `status` will always contain something compatible with the type `"processing" | "error" | "info-required"`.

For example, you could do, `items[2].status = 'invalid text';`

You should ensure the type of `items` like : `const items: Props['items']`

---

[image]

[image]